# How to set initial scroll position of a listview in Android AppWidget?

Tags: android, listview, position, android-appwidget

I have a listview in the AppWidget. I would like to have the listview to start at specific position when user adds the listview to the home screen or after refreshing the widget.  I tried to use the setScrollPostion, but it doesn't work.

e.g:

RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);

......

views.setScrollPosition(R.id.listview_in_widget, 1000);
 appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

The widget is still showing the first item.

I would appreciate it if anyone can give me some hints how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

So you should call setScrollPosition method like this:

```
views.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        views.setScrollPosition(R.id.listview_in_widget, 1000);     
    }
});
```

or in `views.postDelayed` method.

Comment: I am sorry that there is no scrollto or setselection in remoteviews.  Actually, I an trying to implement a circular listview in appwidget. I can do it in normal list view, as I can do setselection  in normal listview. I am trying to implement a calendar appwidget on home screen so that users can scroll up and down. But I have problem to set the initial position of the remote list view.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you question at first, so I edited my answer, hope it helps you.

Comment: Is there any way to get the scroll position in an appwidget/remoteview?

Comment: Unfortunately, Nightly Nexus, I have been searching for a couple of hours on this matter and I couldn't find any way of determining listview scroll position through a remoteview of an appwidget. :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible for a Widget ListView. It took me a few weeks of intermittent attempts and tests, but this is what I've learned.

1) Widgets utilize *RemoteViews* and as a result can only use a subset of functionality of the normal view (ListView in this case). Go to the [ListView source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java) and do a search for *@android.view.RemotableViewMethod*. These annotations determine what a widget could end up using.

2) Check the [RemoteViews source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/RemoteViews.java) and notice on line 776 the *isAnnotationPresent* check. You'll often see an error logged in LogCat that hits this line when you make a method call that is not annotated with *RemotableViewMethod*.

3) You need to ensure you make an *updateAppWidget* call after invoking a method of your RemoteViews instance. Here is an example:

```
//update list item pos
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(_context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
remoteViews.setScrollPosition(R.id.widget_nodes_list, newPos);

//apply pos
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(_context);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(_appWidgetId, remoteViews);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this question. Here is explained what to do, to get it working: [Android RemoteViews ListView Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25618733/android-remoteviews-listview-scroll/25694907#25694907)

Comment: please details the answers Or add as comment.