# Android RemoteViews ListView Scroll

Tags: android

Im trying to scroll a `ListView` to a particular position in an `AppWidget`.

However it does not do anything, i also tried the **setPosition** method but not working.

Also no errors or stack trace.

Code:

```
                    if (list.size() == 0) {
                        loadLayout(R.layout.rooster_widget_header);
                        views.addView(R.id.header_container,
                                views);
                    } else {
                        views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.lvWidget, svcIntent);
                        views.setScrollPosition(R.id.lvWidget, 3);
                    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Issue**: `ListView` does not have any children until it is displayed. Hence calling `setScrollPosition` right after setting adpater has no effect. Following is the code in [AbsListView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/widget/AbsListView.java#4359) which does this check:

```
final int childCount = getChildCount();
if (childCount == 0) {
    // Can't scroll without children.
    return;
}
```

**Solution**: Ideally I would have used `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` for setting the `ListView` scroll position, but it is not possible in case of remote views. Set the scroll position and invoke `partiallyUpdateAppWidget` in a runnable with some delay. I've modified the Android weather widget code and shared in [git hub](https://github.com/manishcm/weatherwidget).

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static HandlerThread sWorkerThread;
    private static Handler sWorkerQueue;

    public MyWidgetProvider() {
        // Start the worker thread
        sWorkerThread = new HandlerThread("MyWidgetProvider-worker");
        sWorkerThread.start();
        sWorkerQueue = new Handler(sWorkerThread.getLooper());
    }

    public void onUpdate(Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; ++i) {
            ...
            final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.lvWidget, svcIntent);

            sWorkerQueue.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    views.setScrollPosition(R.id.list, 3);
                    appWidgetManager.partiallyUpdateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], views);
                }

            }, 1000);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], views);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the screen record. It scrolls to 5th position.

[image: Auto scrolling of ListView in app widget]

Comment: Actually this works but it does not scroll to the right position, i guess i can fix that. Thanks, shut up and take my rep!

Comment: @BenjaminFaal Isn't this verbatim what my answer said?

Comment: No not exactly, because of the postDelayed function.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have the solution, i use it in my own code.
For information, i have some pages & want to show them on demand :

```
getListView().setSelection(((moreServices-1)*20)+1);
```

For you, it will be :

`yourListView.setSelection(3)`;

Hope it helps...

**EDIT**

I think you should see that... that's older, but maybe that's never changed

[How to make a scrollable app widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922114/how-to-make-a-scrollable-app-widget)

Comment: I wish it was, its RemoteViews im using so that is not the way it works.

Comment: Have u tried `setRelativeScrollPosition(int viewId, int offset)` ?

Comment: And `smoothScrollToPosition (int position, int boundPosition)`?

Comment: Its not impossible because those methods are not for nothing in the RemoteViews class. I just think it does not update or sync correctly.

Comment: Have you tried to "notify datas changed" before scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Whit the information I have, I think that the widget doesn't invalidate itself so it doesn't so the changes on it. So I would suggest to refresh your widget. There are two ways to do that, the first one is:

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
```

and there is a second way only in case we don't have direct access to `AppWidgetManager`

```
/**
 * Refresh the views on the widget
 * NOTE: Use only in case we dont have direct acces to AppWidgetManager
 */
private void invalidateWidget() {
    ComponentName widget = new ComponentName(this, YourWidgetProvider.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
    manager.updateAppWidget(widget, mRv);
}
```

Like that the changes should be reflected in the widget. If this doesn't work I am gonna need more details to figure out the problem and edit this answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am gonna need you to share more code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

```
views.setScrollPosition(R.id.lvWidget, 3);
```

is the correct call. Internally, `setScrollPosition(int, int)` calls `RemoteViews#setInt(viewId, "smoothScrollToPosition", position);`.

```
viewId                   :    your ListView's id
"smoothScrollToPosition" :    method name to invoke on the ListView
position                 :    position to scroll to
```

So, you *are* calling the correct method.

Following is a comment for the method `AppWidgetManager#partiallyUpdateAppWidget(int, RemoteViews)` - taken from the source code of `AppWidgetManager.java`. I believe it answers your question: `... Use with {RemoteViews#showNext(int)}, {RemoteViews#showPrevious(int)},{RemoteViews#setScrollPosition(int, int)} and similar commands...`

```
/**
 * Perform an incremental update or command on the widget specified by appWidgetId.
 *
 * This update  differs from {@link #updateAppWidget(int, RemoteViews)} in that the RemoteViews
 * object which is passed is understood to be an incomplete representation of the widget, and
 * hence is not cached by the AppWidgetService. Note that because these updates are not cached,
 * any state that they modify that is not restored by restoreInstanceState will not persist in
 * the case that the widgets are restored using the cached version in AppWidgetService.
 *
 * Use with {RemoteViews#showNext(int)}, {RemoteViews#showPrevious(int)},
 * {RemoteViews#setScrollPosition(int, int)} and similar commands.
 *
 * <p>
 * It is okay to call this method both inside an {@link #ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE} broadcast,
 * and outside of the handler.
 * This method will only work when called from the uid that owns the AppWidget provider.
 *
 * <p>
 * This method will be ignored if a widget has not received a full update via
 * {@link #updateAppWidget(int[], RemoteViews)}.
 *
 * @param appWidgetId      The AppWidget instance for which to set the RemoteViews.
 * @param views            The RemoteViews object containing the incremental update / command.
 */
public void partiallyUpdateAppWidget(int appWidgetId, RemoteViews views) {
    partiallyUpdateAppWidget(new int[] { appWidgetId }, views);
}
```

As the comment indicates, call `partiallyUpdateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)` after `views.setScrollPosition(R.id.lvWidget, 3)`.

The comment also warns you: `This method will be ignored if a widget has not received a full update via {#updateAppWidget(int[], RemoteViews)}`. This might mean that the following calls:

```
views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.lvWidget, svcIntent);
views.setScrollPosition(R.id.lvWidget, 3);
```

should not be made in one update. I suggest that you break these calls into two separate updates:

First:

```
views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.lvWidget, svcIntent);
mAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
```

Second:

```
views.setScrollPosition(R.id.lvWidget, 3);
mAppWidgetManager.partiallyUpdateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

Note that the first one is a *full* update, while the second one is only *partial*.

Comment: @BenjaminFaal `No not exactly, because of the postDelayed function.` Sorry about the late reply. But that's exactly what I meant when I said `I suggest that you break these calls into two separate updates`. I thought that part was clear. Anyways, good luck.